# input type date and min value set by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m), and when I set a min date on a `input type date` via javascript, the min attribute is changed in the HTML but the datepicker doesn't use it.

What am I missing?

```
<input type="date" id="input" />
//...
document.getElementById('input').setAttribute("min", '2013-12-9');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UbPs/)

Comment: Change the option in the fiddle on the left from "onload", to "no-wrap in body", and it adds the attribute.

Comment: @adeneo, no difference: http://jsfiddle.net/5UbPs/2/ - and as I said, I see the `min="2013-12-9"`in the HTML, it just doesn't work...

Comment: This works for me on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.72 m

Comment: @stackErr, I'm using Version 31.0.1650.63 m. Do you get it to work out of the box with my fiddle?

Comment: @Rikard yeah in your fiddle...from the datepicker, everything before 2013-12-09 is grayed out. Though I can manually input any date I want

Comment: @stackErr, maybe a Chrome issue, but Edgars answer is interesting, feels like the W3C defines 2 cases in the dates...

Comment: @Rikard no Edgar is correct...I unconsciously added a 0 before the month in your fiddle :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to w3c (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html)
you just need leading zero in the day:

Instead of
`2013-12-9`

must be
`2013-12-09`

http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/5UbPs/9/

It works :)

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia